# Javascript editor with Photoshop intellisense

Tags: photoshop

I want to get started doing some scripts with Photoshop and I wonder if there's an editor out there that either already has Photoshop's objects or allows to load Photoshop's DOM for intellisense.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Extendscript Toolkit that comes with Adobe suite is pretty much all you need. It even has the entire DOM reference available through the help menu. It does code completion (intellisense) and you can run/debug scripts in the editor.

Comment: Duh..   I'm so new at this that I wrote the entire script in Notepad++. Only after I got it to work and double clicked the .jsx extension, Adobe's editor came up. Thanks for the tip!!